# How could I ensure that Expect will match login prompt everytime?

Tags: java, regex, authentication, expect

I am working on a tool that uses telnet to login to a Nortel DMS switch. The switch is quite old and there is no API or anything to tap in order to login.

So in order to pass login data to the system I am using expect4j (yes I am writing in Java).

This is what the login page looks like.

Telnet CHARACTER MODE. <--- This is part of it

```
Enter User Name
>
[Return key pressed]
Enter Password
>
```

I was thinking I could use a simple regex. Would I want to match with a `\n` or is there a better way?

Comment: What regex do you need? Can you provide sample data for the regex?

Comment: That login prompt is what I need my expect engine (expect4j) to match. Just not sure if I should use an expression to search for it in the output or should I just specify to expect to look for EXACTLY that phrase. But with the line break like that I am wondering if regex would be better.

Comment: I see.. in that case I don't know how to help... sorry :(